# get adminarea from geocoder returns null or not found

Tags: java, android, geocoding, google-geocoder, reverse-geocoding

How can I get state or adminarea from latitude and longitude??

This Code returns: `street, null, country`. However, I need to return only adminarea, not null or not found.

```
 if (isLocationAvailable) {

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
        // Get the current location from the input parameter list
        // Create a list to contain the result address
        List<Address> addresses ;
        try {
            /*
             * Return 1 address.
             */
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mLatitude, mLongitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return ("IO Exception trying to get address:" + e1);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e2) {
            // Error message to post in the log
            String errorString = "Illegal arguments "
                    + Double.toString(mLatitude) + " , "
                    + Double.toString(mLongitude)
                    + " passed to address service";
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return errorString;
        }
}
```

Comment: Probably Geocoding API web service can do this job better. Have you tried it? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding